# Fade in doesnt work when i try to print response text

Tags: jquery, fadein

Maybe do you see where is problem ? It prints output but fade in doesnt work...

```
output = response.text;
$(document).find('.atsakymas[data-custom-id="'+ number +'"]').html(output).fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to hide it first:

```
$(document).find('.atsakymas[data-custom-id="'+ number +'"]').html(output).hide().fadeIn(500);
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kabigiwu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the text will render as visible by default. There is nothing to fadeIn since it's already visible. You should add it wrapped in a hidden element instead.

```
output = '<div style="display:none">' + response.text + '</div>';
```